# javascript: evaluate if given hour is between two hours

Tags: javascript, date, time

So there's plenty of examples on how to calculate the time between two dates.

But in my case, I have a date X. Let's say it's today.
X has a time associate to it, e.g. 08:00 (Or what I get back from `.getHours()`)

I need to know if **the hours of X** are between a start hour (say "07:00") and an end hour (say "12:00")

X will be always retrieved via `getHours()`
The start and end hour of the range have a fixed format (e.g. "07:00" and "12:00")

Performance is an issue, so whatever performs better is preferred (e.g. if it implies using `moment`, that's fine, but if a custom function would perform better, we want that)

My first approach would be, as the formats are fixed, to transform the `.getHours()` to a number, likewise for the range hours, and then calculate...I feel this approach my have trouble with some special cases I may not be aware of?

Comment: `if(X >= 7 AND X <=12) { /* do whatever */ }`

Comment: @Robbert this sounds like maybe the most straightforward thing to do....you shoulod provide this as an answer. I will have to do some tests, also I need to get confirmation if the hours are full hours only or if there could be like half hours and stuff like that...

Comment: @faboolous—you can always convert the values to minutes. But will the range never go over midnight?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [moment-range](https://github.com/gf3/moment-range)

From docs:

> You can also create a range from an ISO 8601 time interval string:

```
var timeInterval = "2015-01-17T09:50:04+00:00/2015-04-17T08:29:55+00:00";
var range = moment.range(timeInterval);
range.contains(X); // true if between interval
```

Comment: Since the OP is concerned about performance, I expect that to be very much slower than alternatives like Brian's.

Comment: @RobG true, we should make some benchmarks. Looking through the [source code](https://github.com/gf3/moment-range/blob/master/lib/moment-range.js#L84) it doesn't seem like an inefficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check part hours, consider converting the hours to minutes, something like the following. How will you deal with ranges that go over midnight? e.g. 23:30 to 01:30.

```js
/*  Determine if the current time is between two provided hours
**  @param {string} h0 - time in format h:mm
**  @param {string} h1 - time in format h:mm
**  @returns {boolean} true if the current time is between or equal to h0 and h1
*/
function betweenHours(h0, h1) {
  var now = new Date();
  var mins = now.getHours()*60 + now.getMinutes();
  return toMins(h0) <= mins && mins <= toMins(h1);
}

/*  Convert hours to minutes
**  @param {string} h - time in format h:mm
**  @returns {number} time converted to minutes
*/
function toMins(h) {
  var b = h.split(':')
  return b[0]*60 + +b[1];
}
```

```html
<form>
  Start time (h:mm)<input name="startHours">
  <br>
  End time (h:mm)<input name="endHours">
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="
   this.form.inRange.value = betweenHours(this.form.startHours.value, this.form.endHours.value);
   ">Check range</button>
  <br>
  Currently in range? <input name="inRange" readonly>
</form>
```

Comment: For ranges that go over midnight, we invert the check. This is about calculating worker shifts, so the ranges are shift times (start - end). We thus need to know if a given hour is between a shift's start and end, and we iterate over all given shift ranges. There are shifts occurring overnight, for those, for each iteration, we were thinking of checking if the range's start is  between the shift's start and it's end! I think your solution totally fits our needs, already upvoted, now implementing and possibly accepting :)

Comment: Since you're dealing with date boundaries, it'd be more robust to use datetimes and check whether a datetime is within a range.

Comment: @pmont—perhaps, but things like shifts in a roster are usually just specified with a start and end time, e.g. 00:00 to 00:06. Only specific shifts have an associated date.

Comment: Sounds like you're handling shift times in a date-agnostic way. That means you have to roll your own custom code to handle date boundaries. Using datetime (even if you simply chose today and tomorrow for any shift), you could use Moment's diff() method to return the difference in hours regardless of whether a date boundary is crossed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you dealing with military tine? (From 0:00 to 24:00)

[`getHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) returns an Integer, and if you are only interested in hours and not minutes, you can use parseInt() to turn the start and end hours into integers as well. For example, `parseInt('07:00', 10)` will return `7`. So if you wanted to create a function to test if the current time is between two hours, it might look something like this:

```
function isBetweenHours(startHour, endHour)
{
    var now = new Date().getHours();
    return now >= parseInt(startHour, 10) && now <= parseInt(endHour, 10);
}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
if( isBetweenHours('07:00', '12:00') ) { //some code here }
```

Comment: Not military time, but European time. In Europe people are used to format the tie that way. This looks cool, maybe what I am aiming at. I will do some tests.

Comment: There is no need for parseInt, the `>` and `<` operators coerce values to number since *now* is a number.

Comment: @RobG When I run `11 > '10:00'` in a JS console, it returns false.