# Best way to compare the elements of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

So I have an array that consists of some number of objects that have both StartTime and Duration member variables. The startTime variable is a string in the format "14:20" and the Duration variable is a number, representing a number of minutes.

Can you guys recommend the best logic for going through the array and combining overlapping elements. For example, if the array had two objects, with the first one having a startTime of "00:00" & duration of 60 and the second object having a startTime of "08:00" & duration of 120 they would be left as separate elements BUT if the second object had a start time of "00:30" and a duration of 120, the two would be  combined into one object with a startTime of "00:00" and a duration of 150.

I have been stuck on the general logic of this for some time, because I can't figure how to handle the case when two blocks are combined, but the new combined block creates a new overlap that must be handled. Am I just thinking about this wrong?! Usually I'm good with this sort of thing but am seriously struggling here.

Comment: Also, im not asking for you to solve this and provide the code at all - just for general guidance on the approach/logic you would use. Thanks.

Comment: no answer - but a suggestion - convert all times to a value of minutes from midnight (ie: a 1AM event with a 1hour duration would be starttime of 60 and endtime of 120). Then if the next start time <120 with a duration of 60, combine the next event duration to the first and so you would have a single event with a start  time of 60 and duration of 120.....  maybe also you could use an array to push the elements into)

Comment: Can you give more context as to why you want it done this way?

Comment: There are plenty of questions here already with answers about how to do that, e.g. [*evaluate if given hour is between two hours*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090969/javascript-evaluate-if-given-hour-is-between-two-hours/35097166#35097166). Convert the start to minutes, the end is then just start plus duration. Then look for overlaps: the start or end of one is within the start and end of another.

Comment: I apologize for the delay guys, i spent this whole night working on a solution. here is the fiddle for it- almost done i need to add handling a few specific cases when the startTime of the new block is equal to the startTime of a block it will be overlapping, but apart from that seems to be working ok. God it's a convoluted solution, hope it helps clarify what i was looking for.
https://jsfiddle.net/hyfp6w9j/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this by creating two trees, one indexed by StartTime and the other indexed by EndTime (StartTime + Duration).  Search both trees for elements that overlapped.  Once the search was complete any found elements would be removed from both trees and the single new element (StartTime = minStartTime(searchResult), EndTime = maxEndTime(searchResult)) would be inserted into both trees.

Uses a little extra storage but I believe this makes your overlap problem trivial.

(Tree implementation left as an exercise :)

Comment: I think this is the answer! My logic in the fiddle I posted does something different and takes way more code than this would.

Comment: @Mark Keane if you think it's the answer, you should accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

expanding on @gavgrif...

i recommend something along these lines.

1. create new array field ['start'] in minutes from midnight  (14:20 -> 188)
2. sort array by 'start' field
3. loop through array looking for overlapping items to merge into segments.  where overlapping is that start of this new item is not greater than the segment end.

php example:

```
$segment  = array('start' => -1, 'end' => -1);  // force new segment on init
$segments = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item['start'] > $segment['end']) {

        // add current segment (ignore initial fake segment) to segments
        if ($segment['start'] > -1) {
            // close out current segment
            $segments[] = $segment;                
        }

        // start new segment
        $segment = $item;

    } else {

        // increment segment end if its later than current segment end
        $segment['end'] = max($segment['end'], $item['end'];
    }        
}

// close out final segment
$segments[] = $segment;
```

Comment: You're assuming the OP can convert PHP to javascript?

Comment: good point.  maybe you could answer in javascript based on my answer and i'll delete my answer.

Comment: I prefer to only answer if the OP provides some code, or the question does not get a good answer within a few hours. And then I'd likely use *reduce* and *some*, or similar. There is not even sample input and output.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, was working on this fiddle for a while. It needs a few more specific use case solutions added but it's working. not pretty imho. https://jsfiddle.net/hyfp6w9j/1/